# ASP.NET Repeater, need new row after every 5 items

Tags: asp.net, repeater

So I have a repeater as follows :

```
                <asp:Repeater ID="footerMenuRepeater" runat="server" onitemdatabound="FooterMenuRepeaterItemDataBound">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <ul id="mainMenuList">
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li class="footerParentSubLists <%# ((FooterMenuItem)Container.DataItem).MenuTitleBoldClass %> <%# Container.ItemIndex == 5 ? "liClearLeft" : string.Empty %>">
                        <div id="footerMenuDiv">
                           <a class="footerMenuHeader" href='<%# ((FooterMenuItem)Container.DataItem).CallToActionLink %>'><%# ((FooterMenuItem)Container.DataItem).Title %></a>
                        </div>
                        <asp:Repeater ID="subItemRepeater" runat="server">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <ul class="footerChildSubList">
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <li><a class="footerMenuItems <%# ((FooterMenuItem)Container.DataItem).ArrowClass %>" href="<%# ((FooterMenuItem)Container.DataItem).CallToActionLink %>"><%# ((FooterMenuItem)Container.DataItem).Title %></a>
                                </li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                </ul>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>                
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </ul>
                </FooterTemplate>
          </asp:Repeater>
```

What I am looking to do is for each 5 items in this repeater is to create a new row, so my mark up would be as follows

**HTML**

```
<ul id="mainMenuList">
    <li> <!-- row 1  -->
        <ul>
            <li class="footerParentSubLists">
                <div>
                   <a class="footerMenuHeader">Header 1</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="footerChildSubList">
                   <li>
                       <a>Sub 1.1</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <a>Sub 1.2</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <a>Sub 1.3</a>
                   </li>
                 </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="footerParentSubLists">
                <div>
                   <a class="footerMenuHeader">Header 2</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="footerChildSubList">
                   <li>
                       <a>Sub 2.1</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <a>Sub 2.2</a>
                   </li>
                 </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="footerParentSubLists">
                <div>
                   <a class="footerMenuHeader">Header 3</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="footerParentSubLists">
                <div>
                   <a class="footerMenuHeader">Header 4</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="footerParentSubLists">
                <div>
                   <a class="footerMenuHeader">Header 5</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="footerChildSubList">
                   <li>
                       <a>Sub 5.1</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <a>Sub 5.2</a>
                   </li>
                 </ul>
            </li>            
        </ul>    
    </li>
    <li> <!-- row 2  -->
        <ul>
            <li class="footerParentSubLists">
                <div>
                   <a class="footerMenuHeader">Header 6</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="footerChildSubList">
                   <li>
                       <a>Sub 6.1</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <a>Sub 6.2</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <a>Sub 6.3</a>
                   </li>
                 </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="footerParentSubLists">
                <div>
                   <a class="footerMenuHeader">Header 7</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="footerChildSubList">
                   <li>
                       <a>Sub 7.1</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <a>Sub 7.2</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <a>Sub 7.3</a>
                   </li>
                 </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Just wondering how I can add this logic to the repeater

Comment: `asp:DataList` has that feature. I don't know if Repeater does. e.g. `RepeatColumns=5, RepeatDirection=Horizotal`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a panel control to the item template with visibility set to "False". Increment a page-level integer variable with each `OnItemDataBound` event. When you reach a multiplier of 5, set the panel's visibility to "True".

Let me know if you need some code to help out.

Answer (score -1):

Use OnItemDtabound Event to check count of repeater item bounds , when it count reaches five , create new row for next five repeater items Simple.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct. How do you create a new row in the OnItemDataBound event?